# No exception of type AuthenticationException can be thrown JAVA

Tags: java, alfresco

I'm trying to authenticate to alfresco using from a Java Class AuthenticationService. Here is the code:

```
public void Authenticate() throws AuthenticationException {

authenticationService.authenticateAsGuest();

}
```

The problem is that I can't run the function because it says that

```
No exception of type AuthenticationException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable
```

I'm using Alfresco 4.2.

The concerned classes are imported from:

```
import org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationException;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.security.AuthenticationService;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Thanks to theMarceloR's post.
First I created a class where I tested this :

```
public class main {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws AuthenticationFault
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws AuthenticationFault {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Class cls = org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationException.class;
  ProtectionDomain pDomain = cls.getProtectionDomain();
  CodeSource cSource = pDomain.getCodeSource();
  URL loc = cSource.getLocation();
  System.out.println(loc);
}
```

After running the program, you will get the missing class in your library. This class is used by AuthenticationException.
I got the error :

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException
```

Then I added the alfresco-core.jar that contains org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException into my classpath. 
I ran the Class again and everything worked fine.

I got that error many times and I've fixed it with this method.

Hope that Help !

Comment: Hi @Tantaoui_El_Mehdi, glad that my answer solved your problem, please accept it when you have a chance.

Answer (score 2):

Decompile `org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationException` and check.

If you want a meaningful name for the exception your Java class will be throwing, you can write your own Exception class.
http://www.java2novice.com/java_exception_handling_examples/create_custom_exception/

If you really want to use that class but you're suspecting that your JVM is loading the wrong one, you can deploy the JSP code below somewhere (e.g., deploy it in the root folder of the web app as 'whereis.jsp'), start your Alfresco server and then check the results of your 'whereis.jsp' page:

```
<%@ page import="java.security.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.net.URL" %>
<%
Class cls = org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationException.class;
ProtectionDomain pDomain = cls.getProtectionDomain();
CodeSource cSource = pDomain.getCodeSource();
URL loc = cSource.getLocation();
out.println(loc);
// it should print something like "c:/jars/MyJar.jar"
%>
```

This will tell you the exact jar that is being loaded by your JVM, it might help you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The exception says it all: you cannot throw such an exception just because the class name says so. It has to derive from `Exception` or at least implement `Throwable`.

Edit: concerning the framework, probably the class has not been designed to be thrown like a normal Java exception.

Do you *have* to put the throws-Statement on the `Authenticate` method?

Edit 2: According to http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/datamodel/org/alfresco/repo/security/authentication/AuthenticationException.html it does implement `Throwable`. Are you sure that you are not in some sort of jar hell? E.g. maybe a different version running in your application container?

Comment: it really smells of class loading issues

Comment: Yes ! When I remove the throws statement Eclipse suggest me to surround with try catch or Add throws declaration. In the description [here](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/service/cmr/security/AuthenticationService.html) they say that the exception have to be thrown !

Comment: I moved back to V 3.3 of the jars but the problem is still there !